# Codeception Acceptance and Phantomjs Cookies outside your domain (Google oAuth)

Tags: codeception

I am at a crossroad where I have the "solution" but I am not sure its the best approach.

Part of my application is oAuth login and I want to test that too (Acceptance).
I have bogus accounts for my oAuth providers that i'll be using to Login. Problem is Cookies.

I am using Phantomjs. Even if I use  clear_cookies: true on my yml file I have this problem where my test cannot login because Google remembers me.
The test is quite simple:

```
public function login_with_oauth(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
  $I->amOnPage('/auth/logout');
  $I->amOnPage('/');
  $I->click(['id' => 'login']);
  $I->click(['id' => 'btn_login_google']);

  @$I->fillField(['id' => 'Email'], $this->login);
  $I->fillField(['id' => 'Passwd'], $this->password);
  $I->click(['id' => 'signIn']);

  $I->waitForText($this->name);
  $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/home');
}
```

First time it works, second it does not because Google remembers the logged in user so it doesnt show the login and password boxes anymore.

If I hit the google logout url (accounts.google.com/logout) it logs the user out, but the next time I try to login it will remember my EMAIL (thus not my password), the email field will be greyed out (disabled) so Codeception can't fill it and goes bananas.

Even if clear_cookies: true worked I would run into a problem where, for all my other test Cests that share the same Session, I would have to login _before(), which would add about 20% more time to run the tests.

The solution I've came up with: is to simply restart phantom before each test. Since phantom is managed by supervisord it is as easy as having a alias in my ~/bashrc, like so:

```
alias codecept=' supervisorctl stop phantomjs && supervisorctl start phantomjs && vendor/bin/codecept'
```

That way I can keep my cookies between each test and I can make sure my oAuth providers cookies are also cleared.

I also tried restarting phantom from within php on the __construct of the oAuth cest but that makes Codecept throw some weird errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage to find a better workaround than those you present upper?

Comment: @FelikZ Nope. Been restarting phantomjs ever since.